# How to check if a route already exists , while generating a dynamic route in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, unique

In my application i need to generate vanity urls for all my users like:
profilename/joinme, where profile name will be unique.
There is a problem , if the profile name is an already existing route like if:
profile_name = users then route will be users/joinme and there is already a resource with the name users.
So i want to check upon creation of these vanity urls that they does not interfere with my existing routes.
Is there an easy way to do that ?
one way that i can think of is getting the formatted output of "rake routes" in a file and then checking  for the existence of that on creation of every routes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of generating dynamic route, you can use dynamic segments in routes.

For example:

```
match ":username/joinme", :to => "users#joinme"
```

Then you can customize behavior in controller as you want.

For the reference:
[Rails Routes - Dynamic Segments](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#dynamic-segments)

---

Also, if you want to control the process of creating new users to prohibit the use of names that are in conflict with the existing routes, you can use the approach described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9913451/986282).

Comment: this is an nice and interesting suggestion , but i guess it currently does not solve my purpose, ex:
profile name of a user is: login
his vanity url: mywebsite.com/login
which interferes with the route: mywebsite.com/login
i basically want to avaoid that

Comment: I thought your question was specifically about routing level. If it's about user-model validations, it's possibly a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9913064/how-can-you-make-sure-a-username-wont-conflict-with-an-existing-route. Check it, it might be exactly what you want.

Comment: perfect this is exactly what i wanted , thanks .can you edit you answer to state that , so that i can mark it as an accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

You should create a list of banned words and check that the username doesn't match any of this words using a validation. An easy way could be:

```
validate :check_banned_words

def check_banned_words
  if %w( admin join login help register ).include? self.username
    errors.add(:username, "this is a banned word!!")
  end  
end
```

If the list of banned words is too long, put it into a yaml file, or create a model just for banned words, in that way you can add new words without redeploy your app

Comment: it will work , "create a model just for banned words" practically will solve all my problems.thanks
i still want to wait for sometime to accept this as an answer , incase someone give me some magic out of rails routes helpers